# Match among values of List

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

I want to write some clean `pattern-matching` code.

I have a `List` of `Regex`:

```
val myList = List(
    ".+\\.a".r,
    ".+\\.b".r,
    ".+\\.c".r.+
)
```

I would like to do something approaching the following:

```
myInputString match {
    case matchAnyRegexFromMyList(s) => //do something
}
```

As an alternative to:

```
myInputString match {
    case regex1(a)|regex2(b)... => //do something
}
```

Is it at least possible to be more concise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your patterns were not pre-compiled you could combine them when they are compiled.

```
val myList = List( ".+\\.a"
                 , ".+\\.b"
                 , ".+\\.c" )

val myListRE = myList.mkString("|").r

"blah.b" match {
  case myListRE() => println("hit")
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible to generate case clauses at runtime. You could write a macro to create them at compile time.

You can use a custom extractor though:

```scala
case class MultiPattern(patterns: List[Regex]) {
  def unapply(s: String): Option[String] =
    patterns.flatMap(_.findFirstIn(s)).headOption
}

val myMultiPattern = MultiPattern(myList)

val myInputString = "x.b"
myInputString match {
  case myMultiPattern(s) => println(s) // output: x.b
}
```

Comment: could of cause also parametrize this and then use a `val` to create the constant.